# Yosemite on SSD boots from USB but not when the SSD is installed internally

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, install

In [another thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/upgrade-macbook-pro-mid-2012-stuck-on-grey-apple-logo) I have explained the issues I have with a clean install of OS X on a SSD.

Now the situation is:

- Yosemite installed on SSD.
- Boots from SSD attached via USB .
- Does not boot from SSD when installed internally.
- I get a beachball and the Mac will not start.

What might the problem be?

Comment: The HDD cables of MacBook Pros are known to be very error-prone. You should consider replacing it. iFixit has the knowledge and parts.

Answer (score 2):

Just because the hardware is set to remember where the last boot was from and will look back to it at the bext boot, I can recommend you to hold down the C button right after you start up the fully assembled system and then select the SSD again.

Also note that the cable that connects the internally placed SSD may be damaged/disconnected somehow or even the Motherboard could have a problematic/defected chip.